# Git workflow design goals met, but it ain't pretty in practice

Tags: git, tfs, workflow

Firstly: We understand why Git does what it's doing. We're looking for a practical way to *deal with it*. Please do not assume we know nothing about Git. We may not know everything but we've spent many hours researching a solution to the problem below.

Several months ago I and another developer on my team started designing a Git workflow for the rest of our team. Our company currently uses TFSVC.

**Our design goals included the following:**

1. Allow isolated testing of features
2. Allow integration testing of features
3. Prevent developers from taking dependencies on unreleased code (this is very important)

**The workflow we've landed on is this:**

1. developer pulls origin/master
2. developer branches master (topic)
3. development happens
4. topic branch published to origin
5. testing happens on origin/topic (in isolation)
6. pull request results in origin/topic branch(es) being merged to origin/develop branch
7. testing happens (integration testing)
8. pull request results in origin/develop being merged to origin/release branch
9. more testing happens (seems redundant but it's really not...details left out for brevity)
10. origin/release merged to origin/master, code deployed to production

The practical upshot of the above steps is that we hit our design goals: isolated testing, integration testing and the piece de resistance is that no developer can take any dependencies on code that hasn't gone through testing and isn't already in production.

All great stuff. But....our commits always snowball. That is to say that once a topic branch’s changes make it all the way through to origin/master and devs pull from origin/master to start the process all over again, we find that pull requests to develop (step 6 above) contain all previous commits. We understand that they only look the same as the previous commits--they're actually different commits, it's the fact that those commits are merged to several branches in succession (and hence have different hashes) that they "come back" over and over.

My question is: can we prune out the "duplicates"? Or can we tell Git to somehow ignore the "duplicates"?

If not, is there any other practical way to deal with this phenomena? Perhaps an adjustment to our workflow that doesn’t add much complexity and still hits all the design goals?

Comment: How about you create a test branch from develop and merge your topic branch to that, and then afterwards simply delete this test branch? Why do you merge to develop if you also intend to merge separately to master? Why not merge develop into master?

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the great applications of `git rebase --interactive`

You may want to consider having the developer rebase to squash their commits into a single commit before any merge occurs, that way master is not polluted with a ton of commits that are irrelevant and hard to parse. Generally each pull request would be squashed into a single commit with a very descriptive commit message before being merged into any other branch.

Here is a good write up on this workflow vs merging which is what you are currently considering: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, this is how I'm reading your question:

- When you say you want to "prevent developers from taking dependencies on unreleased code", you mean you want to "prevent developers from *introducing* [presumably new] dependencies in unreleased code".
- For assorted environment-specific reasons, you have multiple stages of pull requests and testing, where you

  - branch from `origin/master` to `origin/topic`,
  - which is then merged into `origin/develop`,
  - which is then merged into `origin/release`,
  - which is then merged into `origin/master`.

---

I notice you didn't mention where `origin/develop` and `origin/release` are branched from, which leads me to assume that they were both branched off `origin/master` at some point in the past, so when you PR a topic branch into `origin/develop`, it looks something like this:

```
                               T_1 -- T_2 -- ... -- T
                                |                    
    D_orig -- ... -- D_prev ------------------------- D
      /                   \     |                      
  R_orig -- ... ------- R_prev ------------------------ R
    /                       \  /                         
M_orig -- ... ------------ M_prev ----------------------- M
```

which results in the merge commits appearing in the pull request into `D` from `T`, because they're not in the history of `D`.

There really isn't any way around this - the Git model enforces the notion that commits form a DAG, and your workflow is at odds with that model.

To rectify this, every time you merge down, you need to "merge" up again; so for example, when `origin/release` is merged into `origin/master`, you fast-forward `origin/release` to `origin/master`, and the same for `origin/develop`. The reason you want to do this is to keep `origin/develop` as a superset of `origin/release`, which in turn should be kept as a superset of `origin/master`.

You may want to look at [`gitworkflows(7)`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitworkflows.html), which documents how git.git maintains its branches - it's actually remarkably similar to the workflow you describe.